# ubuntu link negotiation

Tags: networking

[image]
Does anyone know what setting 'Link negotiation' to automatic will do?

Before it was set to 'ignore' and every now and them my wired connection would stop working - but the connection icon said it was connected. I would have to manually reconnect to get the internet working.

Will this option fix my problem?

I couldn't find any documentation.

Comment: An "Ethernet" cable can carry various kinds of signals -- the original 10 Mbit/sec "slow" Ethernet, half-duplex and full-duplex 100 Mbit/sec "fast" Ethernet, or 1 Gbit/sec modern Ethernet. Network adapters have built-in means of detecting and negotiating the specific kind of Ethernet they speak to the hub. When this negotiation is successful, the network adapter lights the green "link" LED, to indicate that the computer has a data link to the hub.

Comment: You might find this link helpful - [How does auto-negotiate determine link speeds?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/26488/48387) - it's difficult to know whether changing the option will help since we don't know what the issue is - my *guess* is that it might **if** the issue is one of link quality **and** you manually set it to use a lower-than-advertised rate

Comment: note that with some ethernet printers, setting something like "1 gigabit full duplex (forced)" essentially breaks the printer. if the printer ethernet adapter does not support 1 gigabit, then forcing it on the port will just leave the printer in a state where it only returns an IP 0.0.0.0 no matter what else you do. so from my experience "automatic" was the better option. however this probably only matters in the case where your device does not support the forced value.